# Does mediaelementjs support a single mp4 h264 video accross all platforms?

Tags: html, video, html5-video, mp4, mediaelement.js

I need something that works like videojs that supports native HTML5 when possible, and falls back to flash on browsers that don't support h264 natively. I have videojs working, but because I also need to support MP3 files (not supported by videojs), I thought I would try out mediaelementjs.

Reading the mediaelementjs web site, it looks like this should work, but it's not clear to me whether the flash player will actually play h264 or not. It seems like I may need to include different codecs, which I definitely don't want to do. I want to encode only to h264, and use a player that will play them with flash if the browser doesn't support that codec, and use HTML5 if the browser does.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used mediaelementjs several times and IMHO, I think it's the best way to offer cross-browser support for videos.

A single MP4 file can be used to either play in the native `video` element or it will be played via the SWF.

Comment: Thanks! Can you point me to an example because I've have had no luck getting the flash fallback to work. I can't find an example that shows just a single .mp4 file being used, and the home page shows 2 different ways to use it, and there's nothing indicating that all it needs is a single .mp4 file.

Comment: OK, I'm getting somewhere... Using your example as a template, I can play videos when the video element is hard coded. But when I try to dynamically add the video element using jquery, it does not work.

Comment: HA! In jquery, I was adding the source element as a separate call after I added the video element. IE doesn't like that... it works if you add the entire video element along with the children nodes as a single DOM insertion.